# Hay alguna manera de crear un token Oauth fijo

Tags: javascript, oauth2, oauth, google-oauth

Necesito usar la api de google drive para cargar unos archivos pero en todos los modos de las **Api** para subir un archivo o editar algo piden *OAuth* por lo mismo; me gustaría saber si hay manera de dejar un token fijo, esto, para que el usuario no tenga que validarse a través de una cuenta de google.

He creado una cuenta de servicio con su *private_key_id* pero creo que es necesario también validar el correo que viene con esa *key* y no se cómo ya que solo estoy usando consultas *HTTP*

**Este es un ejemplo con la Api de Blogger**

```js
POST 
Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "blog": {
    "id": ""
  },
  "title": "",
  "content": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola has revisado la documentación; [Usar OAuth 2.0 para aplicaciones de servidor web](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest), detalla como obtener un token de actualización para cuando el usuario no este en línea y se necesite interactuar con Google Drive sin que este este presente, también puedes consultar este enlace [Campo de juego de OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Lo primero que debes hacer es redireccionar al usuario a la pantalla de consentimiento, mediante una url que debes crear con los parámetros que necesites.

Una vez el usuario haya aceptado se devolverá un url con el parámetro **code** el cual se deberá incluir en un petición HTTP.

Sí la respuesta ha sido exitosa se devolverá una cadena de texto de formato json el cual contiene entre otros datos el tokken_access y token_refresh (este último te sirve, para actualizar el tokenn_access cada que el usuario no este presente), debido a que el tokken_access solo tiene validez por poco tiempo.

El formato json que se entrega como respuesta deberás guardarlo en un archivo para su posterior lectura(para las demás funcionalidades listar, crear, eliminar) y actualización caso sea necesario.

En mi caso estoy desarrollando una clase con lenguaje VBA y pude resolverlo con éxito mediante consulta HTTP. ahora sigo desarrollando las demás funcionalidad. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).